# TypeORM Insert Returning - Getting Correct ID Back But As 3 Different Names For Same Value

Tags: insert, typeorm, sql-returning

I'm inserting into a MS SQL table with an identity column, and need the newly inserted ID returned.

This code does the correct insert, and correctly returns the newly created ID.  I can't figure out why I get three different names for the same returned value.

This isn't blocking anything - just curious if there's a cleaner way to only get one returned reference:

```
import "reflect-metadata";
import {createConnection} from "typeorm";
import {getConnection} from "typeorm";
import {Organizations} from "./entity/Organizations"

createConnection().then(async connection => {

    //insert new organization - return organizationId
    const newOrganizationId = await getConnection()
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .insert()
        .into(Organizations)
        .values([
            { organizationName: "Test Organization", organizationId: 2, orgShortName: "TestOrg"}
        ])
        .returning(["organizationId"])
        .execute();
    //  .getSql();
    console.log("Organization Created: ", newOrganizationId);
}).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Here's what's getting returned:

```
Organization Created:  InsertResult {
  identifiers: [ { organizationId: 8 } ],
  generatedMaps: [ { organizationId: 8 } ],
  raw: [ { organizationId: 8 } ]
}
```

Why all three references for the same organizationID value?

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out:

```
console.log(newOrganizationId.raw);
```